# How to derive the perturbativity condition of a simple Kaluza-Klein theory?

Tags: field-theory, perturbation-theory, spacetime-dimensions, kaluza-klein

I thought that the simple $\lambda\phi^4$ theory in 4D is always perturbative if $\lambda<1$.

Below equation 107.1, [PDG review of extra dimensions](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/reviews/rpp2018-rev-extra-dimensions.pdf) says that the 5D Kaluza-Klein theory $$S_5=-\int d^5x dy M_5[|\partial_\mu\phi|^2+|\partial_y\phi|^2+\lambda_5|\phi|^4]$$ this theory is perturbative for energies $E\leq 24\pi^3M_5\lambda^{-1}_5$. Here, $y$ is the extra dimension and $M_5$ is a mass scale. How is this perturbativity limit derived? I have seen the reference given there but it does not explain this. Is there a general method of deriving the perturbativity limit of a theory?

Comment: What is your definition of a theory being "perturbative" here?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I found it in the reference that I linked above. I think it is saying that the interaction term is small so that higher order terms in the perturbation series become progressively smaller?